# How to map 2 table with multipile keys join

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following mapping:

```
<class name="xxx" table="t1" schema="s1" lazy="false">
    <composite-id>     
      <key-property name="OperatorId" column="OPERATOR_ID" />
      <key-property name="GID" column="GID" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="StationName" column="NAME" />


  <join table="t2" schema="s2" optional="true">
      <key column="GID"  property-ref="GID" />
      <key column="OperatorId" property-ref="OperatorId"/>


      <property name="NumberOfKM" column="NumberOfKM" />
    </join>
  </class>
```

It seems that I can't add more then one key to the join,
why? and how can I do it right?

Thanks

Comment: join tables do not support composite key based mappings.

Comment: Do you have another way to join 2 tables with composite keys?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<class name="xxx" table="t1" schema="s1" lazy="false">
    <composite-id>     
      <key-property name="OperatorId" column="OPERATOR_ID" />
      <key-property name="GID" column="GID" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="StationName" column="NAME" />

  <join table="t2" schema="s2" optional="true">
    <key>
        <column name="GID"/>
        <column name="OperatorId"/>
    </key>
      <property name="NumberOfKM" column="NumberOfKM" />
    </join>
</class>
```

Rember that

```
<key>
   <column name="GID"/>
   <column name="OperatorId"/>
</key>
```

for the join on `t2` refer to the key columns existing in `t2`.